# Updating Grid on Webpage

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, html, dom

**Task:**

> Draw a grid with a given number of rows and columns. Each cell can be
>   any color.  The same grid should also be updated at a predetermined
>   time interval.  The grid should cover the entire visible portion of the page in the
>   browser.  Add a context menu with which you can change the parameters of the lattice.

I would really like to hear feedback on the code: syntax, logic and general any comments and tips.

I'm a young programmer so I want to hear real reviews for further development.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/grid.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {

        var grid = new Grid ("20",              // rows
                              "6",              // columns
                              "2000");          // update grid interval

    }

</script>

</head>
<body style="margin:0; height:100%">
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var interval = 0;
var stopUpdateGrid = false;

function Grid(numRows, numColumns, updateInterval) {

    this.numRows = numRows;
    this.numColumns = numColumns;
    this.updateInterval = updateInterval;

    var clientWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    var clientHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

    (function createGrid(rows, columns) {

        var container = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        container.style.width = clientWidth + "px";
        container.style.height = clientHeight + "px";
        container.setAttribute("id", "container");

        for (var i = 1; i <= rows * columns; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            container.appendChild(div);
            div.style.width = (clientWidth - rows - 1) / rows + "px";
            div.style.height = (clientHeight - columns - 1) / columns + "px";
            div.style.cssFloat = "left";
            div.style.margin = "-1px 0 0 -1px";
            div.style.border = "1px solid #000";
            var n = randomColors();
            div.style.backgroundColor = "#" + n;
        }
    })(this.numRows, this.numColumns);

    function randomColors() {
        var min = 0;
        var max = 15;
        var colors = '';

        for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
            rand = Math.round(rand);
            rand = parseInt(rand, 10).toString(16);
            colors = colors + rand;
        }
        return colors;
    }

    (function updateColorsGrid(updInterval, rows, columns) {
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (stopUpdateGrid === false) {
                var container = document.getElementById("container");
                document.body.removeChild(container);
                var grid = new Grid(rows, columns, updInterval);
            }
        }, updInterval);
    })(this.updateInterval, this.numRows, this.numColumns);

    document.onkeyup = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            stopUpdateGrid = true;
            changeGridOptions();
        }
        return false;
    };

    (function createNotification() {
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var notificationContainer = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(notificationContainer);
        notificationContainer.style.width = "500px";
        notificationContainer.style.height = "50px";
        notificationContainer.innerHTML = "Press Enter to show menu change!!!";
        notificationContainer.style.color = "#fff";
        notificationContainer.style.fontSize = "30px";
        notificationContainer.style.position = "absolute";
    })();

    function changeGridOptions() {
        var container = document.getElementById("container");
        var changeOptionsForm = document.createElement("form");
        container.appendChild(changeOptionsForm);
        changeOptionsForm.style.width = "200px";
        changeOptionsForm.style.height = "200px";
        changeOptionsForm.setAttribute("id", "changeOptionsForm");
        changeOptionsForm.style.border = "2px solid #fff";
        changeOptionsForm.style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
        changeOptionsForm.style.position = "absolute";
        changeOptionsForm.style.left = clientWidth - 220 + "px";
        changeOptionsForm.style.top = "15px";

        var changeRowsText = document.createElement("div");
        changeOptionsForm.appendChild(changeRowsText);
        changeRowsText.style.width = "50px";
        changeRowsText.style.height = "20px";
        changeRowsText.style.margin = "10px";
        changeRowsText.innerHTML = "Rows:";
        changeRowsText.style.cssFloat = "left";

        var changeRows = document.createElement("input");
        changeOptionsForm.appendChild(changeRows);
        changeRows.type = "text";
        changeRows.style.width = "100px";
        changeRows.style.height = "20px";
        changeRows.style.border = "2px solid #000";
        changeRows.style.margin = "10px";
        changeRows.style.cssFloat = "left";

        var changeColumnsText = document.createElement("div");
        changeOptionsForm.appendChild(changeColumnsText);
        changeColumnsText.style.width = "50px";
        changeColumnsText.style.height = "20px";
        changeColumnsText.style.margin = "10px";
        changeColumnsText.innerHTML = "Columns:";
        changeColumnsText.style.cssFloat = "left";

        var changeColumns = document.createElement("input");
        changeOptionsForm.appendChild(changeColumns);
        changeColumns.type = "text";
        changeColumns.style.width = "100px";
        changeColumns.style.height = "20px";
        changeColumns.style.border = "2px solid #000";
        changeColumns.style.margin = "10px";
        changeColumnsText.style.cssFloat = "left";

        var changeDelayUpdateGridText = document.createElement("div");
        changeOptionsForm.appendChild(changeDelayUpdateGridText);
        changeDelayUpdateGridText.style.width = "50px";
        changeDelayUpdateGridText.style.height = "20px";
        changeDelayUpdateGridText.style.margin = "10px";
        changeDelayUpdateGridText.innerHTML = "Delay Update:";
        changeDelayUpdateGridText.style.cssFloat = "left";

        var changeDelayUpdateGrid = document.createElement("input");
        changeOptionsForm.appendChild(changeDelayUpdateGrid);
        changeDelayUpdateGrid.type = "text";
        changeDelayUpdateGrid.style.width = "100px";
        changeDelayUpdateGrid.style.height = "20px";
        changeDelayUpdateGrid.style.border = "2px solid #000";
        changeDelayUpdateGrid.style.margin = "10px";
        changeDelayUpdateGrid.style.cssFloat = "left";

        var changeButton = document.createElement("input");
        changeOptionsForm.appendChild(changeButton);
        changeButton.type = "button";
        changeButton.value = "change";
        changeButton.style.width = "100px";
        changeButton.style.height = "25px";
        changeButton.style.margin = "20px 50px";
        changeButton.style.cssFloat = "left";

        changeButton.onclick = function() {
            numRows = changeRows.value || numRows;
            numColumns = changeColumns.value || numColumns;
            updateInterval = changeDelayUpdateGrid.value || updateInterval;
            changeOptionsForm.style.display = "none";
            stopUpdateGrid = false;
            document.body.removeChild(container);
            var grid = new Grid(numRows, numColumns, updateInterval);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Please leave the formatting alone.  We are trying to make the question more readable for people who want to answer can understand the question.

Comment: What are you going to do if the user resizes their browser

Comment: I do not know why, but I never thought of that! then probably block "container" need to make 100%!

Answer (score 5):

Just a couple of things that I really feel strongly about (didn't work line for line through your code though).

## Seperation of logic and presentation

Yes, there is a `.style` object, however this does *not* mean you should use it as the primary way to style your objects. Instead just apply the corresponding class (either through the `classList` object or the backwards compatible `class` property), and only the really dynamic things (random background colour for example) should indeed be done through Javascript.

## Always use `addEventListener`

In a simple stand alone case it doesn't matter, but at some point later you often end up regretting using things like `.onclick`, so instead use `.addEventListener('click',function(){...})`.

## Generating HTML

You're doing a great job at using the proper DOM methods to build up your html, however sometimes code becomes more readable by building up a html *string* which you apply with `.innterHTML`. Or alternatively using a templating library might be an even better idea, though you would have to find one which fits your taste (just look around on google, I used to use pure.js for example).

Comment: I did not use CSS to show their knowledge of javascript! probably it was wrong)

about advice, thank you very much, you made ​​a contribution to the development of my future;)

Comment: @sparcmen If you want to thank the reviewer, up-vote his question :)

Comment: You seem like a re-activated user, you should come join us in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) sometime :)

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- This has the parameters split over multiple lines, that is to be avoided, you could do this:

  ```
  window.onload = function () {

    var rowCount = 20,
        columnCount = 6,
        refreshRate = 2000,
        grid = new Grid( rowCount, columnCount, refreshRate );
  }
  ```
- As David Mulder mentioned, your code could be a lot shorter if you moved more into CSS. In fact once you fixed that, I would re-submit this code. It would be interesting.
- `stopUpdateGrid` should be part of `grid`, unless you meant all instances of `Grid` to stop in `document.onkeyup` which should be commented in that case.
- Same goes for `interval`
- You are never using `grid` in `var grid = new Grid(rows, columns, updInterval);` so you might as well just do `new Grid(rows, columns, updInterval);`
- Other than that your code is very clean, JsHint.com could find close to nothing, it is readable, follows lowerCamelCasing, variables are well named, fun to review.

Comment: I will repurpose the code using CSS and acknowledge all the advice and comments)